# Parallel printing not supported on 12.04LTS

Tags: printing

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and now CUPS printing cannot find my printer. It's an HP 970cse and uses parallel printing. Isn't parallel printing supported anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the lp, ppdev, and parport_pc kernel modules are loaded, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe lp
sudo modprobe ppdev
sudo modprobe parport_pc
```

More information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#Parallel_port_printer