# HP Laser Jet 4 Plus Printer

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I'm told Windows 10 doesn't support my printer. I'm looking for a solution and am willing to change operating systems if that's what it takes. Does Ubuntu support an HP Laser Jet 4 Plus printer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not without possible issues.

See [this](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_4_plus) link from HP and from which the earliest version of HPLIP to use.

As this is an old printer using only parallel printer interface you may have to follow some old threads to get it to work see this earlier Ask Ubuntu thread [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129379/parallel-printing-not-supported-on-12-04lts)

One of the first things to do is check that the OS can see your parallel printer port by following these instructions:

Parallel port printer

Make sure that the printer is connected to your system and powered on.

Open a terminal/console and check if the lp, ppdev, and parport_pc kernel modules are loaded:

```
lsmod | grep lp
lsmod | grep ppdev
lsmod | grep parport_pc
```

Check if the kernel detected the parallel port during bootup:

```
dmesg | grep par
```

Check if the device files of the parallel port(s) are created and have the correct permissions and ownerships:
    ls -l /dev/lp* /dev/parport*

Check if the printer auto-detection result appears in the kernel's virtual file system:

```
ls -l /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe* 
sudo cat /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe*
```

Find out if your printer gets detected by CUPS:

```
lpinfo -v
```

Run the parallel port CUPS backend separately, once with standard user privileges and once as root:
    $ /usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel 
    $ sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel 
    Attach the output of the above commands to the bug report.

Note that problems can be caused not only by CUPS, but also by the kernel (package "linux"), HPLIP (package "hplip"), and several third-party printer drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Check this page for the list of supported printers: [hp's Developer Portal | All Supported Printer Models](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). It includes HP LaserJet 4 Plus Printer.